# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have tried to install `gulp-sass` latest version with `npm i gulp-sass --save-dev`  in the begining I got a lot of errors but later solved them. But whenever I try to run gulp I got this error:

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:166:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
```

I have tried to fix the problem with `npm rebuild node-sass --force` but it rise error too.

```sh
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf> npm rebuild node-sass --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

> node-sass@4.14.1 install C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/win32-x64-88_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.14.1/win32-x64-88_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\HPortf\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@15.0.1 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16) 
gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:183:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\HPortf\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v15.0.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
node-sass@4.14.1 C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf\node_modules\node-sass
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\HPortf>
```

- node and npm version

```sh
$ node --version
v15.0.1
user (master *) HmdPort
$ npm --version
6.14.8
```

Comment: So did you go to https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1? That hasn't been built for Node 15, you'll have to downgrade Node until [v5](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v5.0.0) gets released.

Comment: you mean I should install a version less than node 15?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Unless you really need some specific feature I'd generally recommend using the active LTS version (listed on the [home page](https://nodejs.org/en/) as *"Recommended For Most Users"*), currently v14.

Comment: I got you I installed current version of node I need to install LTS version, I will try and see.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe it was a node version problem I have donwload stable version and I have delete node_module and reinstall things and worked well, you can post and answer so others take advantages of it, again thank you so much for paying my attention to it.

Comment: the [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) project itself states, that it is deprecated and recommends to move to dart-sass. In the context of Gulp the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65050165/2776727) of @ClovisRosa manages it gracefully.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe).

Worked for me:

1. install / downgrade node.js to a stable version (LTS) like  [14.15.0](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. install the compatible node-sass version via `npm install node-sass@4.14.0`; you can find the list [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), or even install `gulp-sass`with `npm i gulp-sass --save-dev`.

[direct link to list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQIFo.png)

Comment: Yes the problem was with current version of node that has some bugs, so installing LTS version will fix the issues than you can install gulp sass without installing node-sass without precising a version coz the latest one is compatibel with LTS node version :)

Comment: Current node version 15.X does not supported by some node-modules. Had to spend much time to review each node-module and decided to downgrade node version. thanks for your posting.

Comment: In the link you give to the node-sass entry on npm, what is the difference between "NodeJS" and "Node Module". How do I install a specific version of "Node Module"?

Comment: Does not work on MAC M1. Nothing works on MAC M1 :')

Comment: Its end of 2021 and the error still exists even for the Node LTS version 16! Precisely: "Unsupported runtime (102)". Also, node-sass v6.0.1 doc says it is compatible with v16 on Linux

Comment: This solution worked for me on MacBook Pro (Big Sur) 64-bit

Comment: yes, I had installed the latest node version v17.x， and this problem solved only when I change my node version to 14. on mac you can use brew install node@14

Comment: `14.15.1` has worked also.

Answer (score 126):

None of the above worked for me. So, instead I uninstalled node-sass and installed just sass. No more errors!

```
npm uninstall node-sass
```

```
npm i sass
```

Comment: wfm after my edit to crg’s answer – macOS 10.15.7 (if that matters)

Comment: This seems to work for me as well. My Vue2 environment failed to start with "npm run watch" after I upgraded npm & node so that I could start building Vue3 projects. Removing node-sass on Vue2 project and replacing it with sass fixed running watch/serve

Comment: Plus [sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) is now the recommanded package since [LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) .

Comment: Thought I'd try this first before downgrading NodeJS, I'm very happy I did! I had 120 errors before, fixed all of them. +1

Comment: After doing this it just asks for node-sass again.

Comment: Other answers didn't work for me but this solved the problem. (MacOS M1 chip)

Answer (score 62):

This command in the console worked for me:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: I was working with node v16.x and updated to v18.16.0, didn't solve the issue but I used this command line and it works! I'm on MacOs Ventura 13.3

Comment: I just updated node from v14.x to node v18.x and this fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 42):

> Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto Dart Sass.

the `node-sass` package is deprecated.

Instead install `sass` instead like this:

```
yarn add sass -D
# or
npm i sass --save-dev
```

Comment: But in my case I have tried to install gulp-sass where the error rised up. Maybe gulp-sass is dependent in node-sass yet

Comment: Worked for me...Cypress React component testing (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/react) failed to load (with the error indicated in the OP question) otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: that worked for me. I suppose this is the fastest solution.

Comment: in my case worked fine...

Answer (score 27):

remove node-sass

```
npm remove node-sass
```

then install

```
npm i node-sass@npm:sass -D
```

Node sass project is deprecated. Don't use it anymore!

https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated

The new project uses Dart. https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass

Answer (score 24):

Firstly uninstall

```
npm uninstall node-sass
```

then install

```
npm i sass
```

this will work definitely

Comment: Thanks! it actually did, can you explain a bit how this solves the issue?

Comment: this is the solution. thanks.

Comment: This solution definitely worked for me!

Answer (score 12):

I ran to the same problem and I found that the best solution is to use `gulp-dart-sass`. You won't need to downgrade your Node.js(I'm using it with Node version: v15.3.0 right now)

Simple replace gulp-sass to [`gulp-dart-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dart-sass)

Comment: Sometimes the non stable version create many problems. Even if u can manage this problem with this command u may face other problems, you will spend ur life fixing errors! this is bad. So it is alwyas better to install a stable version.

Comment: This is actually a super solution, as the [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) project itself is deprecated now and recommends to move to dart-sass officially.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue after updating my Node.js version from 14.15.5(LTS) to 15.8.0.
In order to resolve this issue I downgraded Node.js version back to 14.15.5(LTS).

I used chocolatey to downgrade NPM. If you don't have chocolatey installed in your system, 
you can get Chocolatey from [here](https://chocolatey.org/).

Now to downgrade Node.js we have to do the following steps

1. Uninstall latest version of the Node.js 
   For that you have to use this code. 
   `choco uninstall nodejs`
2. To install the desired version of Node.js,
   `choco install nodejs --version $VersionNumber`

in my case,
`choco uninstall nodejs`
`choco install nodejs --version 14.15.5`

this solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

**Worked for me**

1. npm install with specific node version that you need

   This the version of node that I am using

   `npm install -g npm@6.14.6 --target_arch=x64`
2. Clean cache

   `npm cache clean --force`

   `rm -rf /node_modules`
3. Install node-sass

   `npm install node-sass --save-dev --force`
4. If you have errors and warnings try:

   `npm fund`

   `npm audit fix`

   `npm install -g npm@6.14.6 --target_arch=x64`

   `npm start`

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue, and here's how I was able to fix it:

Firstly, you have to know which `node-sass` version you are using in your project, then go upgrade or downgrade your current `nodeJS` version to the compatible version with your current `node-sass` version, you can know that from [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).

Ofc, stop the server, and close your IDE.

So, the best way to upgrade or downgrade the `nodeJS` version, has mentioned above in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66205976/12458449), then remove the `node_modules`, and `package-lock.json` and install again.. You can do it as such:

`npm cache clean --force`

`rm -rf /node_modules package-lock.json`

`npm install`

`npm audit fix`

`npm run <your_script_name>`

*Good Luck!*

Answer (score 2):

For me,
the issue happened after I updated my node version to 16,
I downgraded the node version to 14.17.6 and had to uninstall the node-sass version 6 and reinstall node-sass version 4.14 which is compactible with node 14+

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm i node-sass@4.14
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the only solution was to downgrade NodeJs from 16(my current version) to 10 version (it can be any version below probably), tried almost all that were advised here and on other websites and only this helped.

Answer (score 1):

1. In my case I removed `node-sass` with `npm remove node-sass`
2. then I installed `node-sass` `npm i node-sass@next`
3. restarted server

- Hurray! everything worked fine *

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue (WINDOW) -Fixed for me after following the below steps.

1. Open the Gitbash terminal.
2. `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
3. `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`
4. `command -v nvm`

> Fixed issue for me, I could see nvm installed :)

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue and I solved it by installing the latest version `npm i node-sass`(v9.0) as of Oct,2023) and then rebuilding dependencies using `npm rebuild node-sass`

MacOS Sonoma (14.0)

Node - v16.20.1

Comment: I was able to keep `node-sass` v8.0.0 and simply run `rpm rebuild node-sass` and it worked fine. FWIW, I'm on Node v21.1.0. Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed to make it work.

- brew uninstall node  (Or uninstall with the package manager you used)
- brew install n
- sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n
- n 14.15.0

Answer (score 0):

For any1 having this problem with SPFx

If you have upgraded your node version, steps to upgrade your SPFx solution

1. Create a side clean SPFx project (Webpart or Extension (Extension is only with 2019+))
2. Save somewhere (just in case) the following files package.json, tsconfig.json, package-lock.json
3. Copy from your new project to your old project only 2 files  package.json, tsconfig.json
4. Run gulp clean
5. Run npm install
6. Run gulp build ect.

summerized [here](https://bresleveloper.blogspot.com/2021/07/sfpx-node-saas-error.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party but what I did is install [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and add a small function in .bashrc to change node version as I need using an alias.

```
function switchNodeVersion()
{
  nvm use 14.6.0
  node-sass [options] <input.scss> [output.css]
  nvm use 16.13.0
}
alias swap=switchNodeVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install nvm on your machine to switch between various node versions to suit the projects that are using downgraded versions of node.

Then using this capability you can essentially switch between the node versions on your machine.

Here is a great guideline for achieving this.
[Setting Up NVM](https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/)

Another option is to switch between the different node versions you have installed by adding the specific node version you want your project to use:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {....
```

Then once your node versioning issue is corrected, you can install node-sass..but keep in mind some node-sass versions will not be compatible with deprecated versions of node and vice versa.

But in general, if you want to avoid version issues with your dependencies, use [docker](https://www.docker.com/) and dockerize your projects into containers. It will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was the node version witch had to be 14 and i was at 16

Answer (score 0):

node-sass-middleware is deprecated. In place of this install sass-middleware.

```
npm uninstall node-sass-middleware

npm install sass-middleware
```

```html
const sassMiddleware = require('sass-middleware');

const path = require('path');

const sassMiddlewareOptions = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'sass'),
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets'),
  debug: true,
  outputStyle: 'compressed'
};


app.use(sassMiddleware(sassMiddlewareOptions));
```

Now you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I just downgraded node version from 18 to 16 and it worked