# Module Error (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, cypress, storybook

I am facing this issue on running App.test.tsx on cypress test runner. Please help

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/764EM.png)

Comment: Click on the error for Image

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I guess it is nothing to do with cypress, may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612707) one help?